# Inherit from ViewComponent without invoke the parent ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am using ASP .Net Core `ViewComponent`  and I have a common function shared between components so I decided to make a common `ViewComponent` and all other components must inherit from it

I tried this first

```
    public class CommonViewComponent: ViewComponent
    {
       //some methods
    }
```

and the child component like this

```
 public class SubDealsViewComponent: CommonViewComponent
 {
      public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
      {
          //calling some methods from the parent
      }
 }
```

in this situation, I faced an error that the parent component must contain `Invoke()` or `InvokeAsync()`

also when I made Invoke() method for the parent component I got this error

> InvalidOperationException: View component
> 'Components.SubDealsViewComponent' must have exactly one public method
> named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of reusing members, your parent view component class can be declared as `abstract` and that way it does not need to have an `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method defined, like this:

```
public abstract class CommonViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
   //some methods
}
```

That makes sense because otherwise it can be a valid usable view component but that's not your purpose (to use it directly).

Comment: It's works 
yes I am not gonna use it directly, I will use it to put some methods that uses HttpContext and Sessions instead of injecting IHttpContextAccessor in all components